# unable to access nodeIP:port, serviceIP:port or podIP:port in minikube k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networking

I am using k8s in minikube under Ubuntu and deployed nginx server. Which i want to access from different level eg from serviceip, nodeip or pod ip and none of them is reachable.Not sure why?? I am running my curl command to access ip:port from the ubuntu host machine where minikube node is installed. below is the log

```
/home/ravi/k8s>kgp
NAMESPACE     NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       nginx-deployment-775bf4d7fb-jqxxv   1/1     Running   0          13m     172.17.0.3     minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-gtsl7            1/1     Running   0          9h      172.17.0.2     minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-minikube                       1/1     Running   0          9h      192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube             1/1     Running   0          9h      192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube    1/1     Running   0          9h      192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-nphlc                    1/1     Running   0          7h28m   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube             1/1     Running   0          9h      192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system   storage-provisioner                 1/1     Running   21         9h      192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>kgs
NAMESPACE     NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE   SELECTOR
default       kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  9h    <none>
default       nginx-service   NodePort    10.101.107.62   <none>        80:31000/TCP             13m   app=nginx-app
kube-system   kube-dns        ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   9h    k8s-app=kube-dns
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>kubectl describe service nginx-service
Name:                     nginx-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              Selector:  app=nginx-app
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.101.107.62
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31000/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.3:8000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>curl 172.17.0.3:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 8000: No route to host
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>curl 192.168.1.52:31000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.52 port 31000: Connection refused
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>curl 10.101.107.62:80    ---> also hangs
......
......

/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>kubectl get node -o wide
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION    INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
minikube   Ready    master   9h    v1.18.20   192.168.49.2   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS   5.13.0-40-generic   docker://20.10.3
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>
/home/ravi/k8s>curl 192.168.49.2:31000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 31000: Connection refused
/home/ravi/k8s>


/home/ravi/k8s> kubectl logs nginx-deployment-775bf4d7fb-jqxxv   ---> no log shown


/home/ravi/k8s>cat 2_nginx_nodeport.yaml 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: nginx:1.16
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
---        
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP           
      nodePort: 31000
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8000         
/home/ravi/k8s>

root@nginx-deployment-775bf4d7fb-jqxxv:~# curl 172.17.0.3:80  ---> working on port 80 instead of 8000 as set in yaml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: consider adding the info like, how are you trying to access the pod/service? from where are you trying to access it.

Comment: i have shown in the log, i have used curl command.            curl ip:port

Comment: sorry, I missed that. Can you tell what is `192.168.1.52`

Comment: 192.168.1.52 is the ip of my ubuntu host machine where minikube cluster is installed. since nodeport is externally accessible hence I guess from host machine i should be able to access.

Comment: you need to do `kubectl get node -o wide` get the node `ip` and then curl to it from your local machine.  OR create a temp pod within your cluster and then curl from there.

Comment: Most likely above comment should resolve your issue. If it does, then delete the question as it is not an appropriate question and may be closed later.

Comment: i got the ip from kubectl get node -o wide  and tried to curl using that but still not working. Updated the cmd output in main thread.     Surprisingly, no log is seen in kubectl log output of the pod ...though pod is running. plz see the cmd output in main thread.

Comment: Hiw about curl from other pod ?

Comment: instead of other pod i logged right into nginx pod and ran the curl command. surprisingly curl is working from inside on port 80 while i configured nginx container port and target port 8000 (not 80) see my attached yaml file